# Java Threads - Keep function in sync with multiple returning values from threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This is just a concept :

- I want to have a int be updated, by a function that is running inside multiple threads.
- My function randomly chooses an int and checks if it's bigger than the existing int.
- If so it updates the variable.

How do I ensure my values never clash or my function is looking at an older value not yet updated?

I'm new to threads so any information is valuable.

Answer (score 2):

This a job for `AtomicInteger`!

```
AtomicInteger atomic;
...
int newValue = atomic.accumulateAndGet​(rand, Math::max);
```

Comment: What if my function returned a class instead of int? Could i "atomic" my class?

Comment: @walkman The equivalent for reference types is `AtomicReference`. It has similar methods, except the ones explicitly to do with integers. (I guess I should add, you need to replace the whole object with that (preferably an immutable one, like `Integer`, but needn't be), you can't just update a field.)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ensure my values never clash?

If you are new to threads, then I would say, use a synchronized block:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
int global_r = 0;
...
while (true) {
    int r = random.nextInt();
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (r > global_r) {
            global_r = r;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Only one thread at a time can enter the `synchronized(lock)...` block. A thread that tries when another thread already is in it will be forced to wait.

One should always try to have threads spend as little time as possible inside a `synchronized(...)` block, which is why I generate the random number *outside* of the block, and only do the test and the assignment inside it.

---

Another answer here suggests that you use `AtomicInteger`.  That works too, but it is not what I would recommend for somebody who is taking their very first steps toward understanding how to use threads.

Comment: Complicating just a bit: I want to return a class instead of an int from my function, and then checking if a value from that class is bigger. Will this suggestion still be viable?

Comment: @walkman, There's two things you need to know about `synchronized`. (1) No two threads will ever be allowed to be synchronized on the same object (e.g., `lock`) at the same time. and (b) whatever one thread does before it leaves a synchronized block is guaranteed to be visible to another thread that subsequently synchronizeds on the same lock object. Just as, in my example, the synchronized block prevents one thread from updating `global_r` while another thread is testing it... You can use the same principle to prevent threads from interfering when they update or test other kinds of data.